# How to respond to "Good Morning" from a colleague who's in place with 10 hr time difference?

Tags: greetings

So, a colleague of mine, who's in a place with 10 hr time difference than mine, called me up during my morning (9am), his late night (11pm), and said "Good Morning". As this happened for the first time with me, I just replied with "Oh hello. Good ... err Night ... to you" & had a few seconds of awkward moment & continued with our work talk.

So I was wondering, what would be my proper response in this situation?

Comment: Just stick to ***Hello*** and ***Goodbye*** in such contexts. The only justification I can see for identifying *your specific* time-frame in such "cross-time-zone" greeting contexts is to make the point that the caller should have been more considerate, and *shouldn't* be calling you about work-related issues just when you're about to go to bed!

Answer (score 1):

"Good night" is a farewell expression: something you say to end the conversation, not a greeting. This is probably the source of the awkwardness. Instead you could say "good evening." "Good morning" would also be perfectly fine since this colleague was obviously familiar with the time zone difference.